# Filter rows according to lists

Tags: r, filter

I'm currently working with a dataset that looks like this

```
                   1           2        3          4
    1           5.6269867  5.359966  6.085808  6.094766
    100         6.6521737  6.548485  6.692246  5.964344
    1000       11.6311641 11.801981 11.968012 12.020267
    10000      10.8092223 10.651230 10.220897 10.240394
    100009676   5.2990093  5.262938  6.412096  5.964344
    10001       7.5355817  7.325389  7.277273  6.303389
    100033431   3.3413615  4.089792  4.018772  4.476827
    100037417   3.4658668  5.262938  3.925580  1.125316
(...)
```

I would like to filter this df according to a df2, which only contains rownames of rows of interest in df1. This df2 looks like this:

```
1        1958
2       79094
3       54541
4        2354
5         388
6       10365
7       83667
8        3725
9        8553
10       4739
```

Is there any quick way to do this? df1 is huge, and so are filters (df2)

Comment: `df1[df1[,1] %in% df2[,1],]`?

Comment: @Ryan more like: `df1[rownames(df1) %in% df2[,1],]`

Comment: That worked fine!! thanks so much!